# How to edit the "background" in a developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I want to change my story "background" (at the bottom of the page) at https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/856090?view=Cv
but I see no edit button.

Please help me to edit my background.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Story view" and then find the Background box in your timeline. Click the gear icon at the top right of the section to edit or delete the section.

You cannot edit anything directly from the traditional view.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer provided by @animuson, which I found very useful. Adding some additional information to enable others looking for this solution to find it faster.

Step 1: Go to "Developer Story" Tab

Step 2: Click on the "Story View" Tab

[image]

Step 3: Scroll Down to "Background" section of the Timeline and click on the Gear

[image]

Step 4: Then click on the Edit option and change the content of the summary section.

Note: you will be required to add a date according to the recent changes I have notices in this section.