# Has the "background" category been removed from Developer Story? If not, how can I edit it?

Tags: support, developer-story

I want to add a "background" (where you come from/description) to my Developer Story, but there is no longer a Background category there. Has this feature been removed or simply hidden?

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348856/how-to-edit-the-background-in-a-developer-story), but my question is not a duplicate of that, because the information provided there implies you already have such a section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What was once the *Background* section in the old-style CV was converted to a *milestone* (the `.*` icon) in the new Developer Story model. I have one of those on my timeline still, with both the *category* and *title* fields set to *Background*, but the date is left empty.

You can still add such a milestone entry yourself and give it the same title and category, but you are now required to give it a month and year.

Milestones only have a start date, so take into account that they’ll sort weirdly in the dev story view: [Items on my Developer Story are appearing out of order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369518/items-on-my-developer-story-are-appearing-out-of-order)